# Can anybody explain "permanent votes on the Fed's committee" for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Beyond Fed policy, Trump will also have the power to nominate several Fed officials. Two board appointments can be made as soon as he arrives at the White House. They will have permanent votes on the Fed's committee. In early 2018, Yellen and Fischer's terms also expire. There's further speculation that Fed governor Daniel Tarullo may step down once Trump takes office.

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2016/11/21/news/economy/fed-fischer-trump/index.html?iid=SF_LN

Comment: This appears to be a question about the Fed, not about English. What is it about the language of the phrase that you do not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that they will have voting powers in the committees  that ***[the FED](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomc.htm)***  holds regularly in which monetary policy measures (like raising or lowering interest rates) are decided.

Some members are permanent, other serve a one-year term.

Comment: typo: comm **i** tees